# How to override `issueToken` method in Laravel/Passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to override the `issueToken` method located in the `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController` without adding a new route i.e(api/oauth/token). I have built my own `AccessTokenController` that performs the functionality that i want but when i make a call to `oauth/token`, the parent method is being executed and not my implementation.. am i misisng something to complete the override?

```
<?php
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
   use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
   use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
   use \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController as ATC;

   class AccessTokenController extends ATC {

     public function issueToken(ServerRequestInterface $request){
       try {
         // Fetching username from request
         $username = $request->getParseBody()['username'];
         // Fetching the User
         $user = User::where('email', '=', $username);
         // Genereting token
         $tokenResponse = parent::issueToken($request);
         //convert response to json string
         $content = $tokenResponse->getBody()->__toString();
         $content['email'] = $user['emial'];
         //convert json to array
         $data = json_decode($content, true);
         return $data;

       } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
         return ['Message' => 'The suer credentials were incorrect!'];
       }catch (\Exception $e) {
         return ['Message' => 'Exception: '.$e];
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: As of Laravel 8 it is `$request->getParsedBody()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just overriding the route in `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php` is enough.

Make sure you add: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;` at the top of the file!

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Passport::routes();

    Route::post('/oauth/token', [
        'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken',
        'as' => 'passport.token',
        'middleware' => 'throttle',
    ]);
}
```

Output of `php artisan route:list --name=passport.token`:

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name                    | Action                                                                    | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST     | oauth/token             | passport.token          | App\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken                     | throttle   |
|        | POST     | oauth/token/refresh     | passport.token.refresh  | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\TransientTokenController@refresh        | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/tokens            | passport.tokens.index   | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@forUser | web,auth   |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/tokens/{token_id} | passport.tokens.destroy | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@destroy | web,auth   |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: i made the changes you suggested but i am still hitting the parent method and not my implementation. as a matter of fact if i set the wrong path i.e('uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\NONE\AccessTokenController@issueToken',) to my controller it does not give me an error so i dont think it is even looking there. @keyboardSmasher

Comment: That's strange. I tested the code prior to answering, and it works for me. Maybe your routes are cached? `php artisan route:clear` @juan_code18

Comment: Fair enough. I edited the typo and ran the code on my server. You can see the output of `php artisan route:list` `oauth/token` is overridden on my installation. Anyway, good luck. :) @juan_code18

Comment: Do you know where it goes after AuthServiceProvider? I got error 500 and tried to debug it, it seems like the error is after all the functions inside the authserviceprovider

Answer (score 0):

The route is hardcoded in the code inside of the vendor.

I suggest you redeclare the route in your app, change this code to a middleware then wrap the route around it.

Comment: how would i change my code to a middleware? sorry im fairly new to PHP and laravel for the matter?
the route im assuming i would redeclare in the routes directory in `web.php` or `api.php` @meda

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8, possibly others, if the intent is to perform additional checks on the state of a user to determine if they should be allowed to login, you can create a function in your `User` class like the following. Passport will check for this and call it if present.

```
    // Used by Laravel Passport UserRepository
    // We implement it to prevent logins of deactivated users.
    public static function findAndValidateForPassport($username, $password)
    {
        $user = User::where('email',$username)->first();

        // Do we have this user
        if(null === $user) return null;

        // Are they deactivated
        if($user->fDeactivated()){
            return null;
        }

        // does password match
        if(Hash::check($password, $user->password)){
            return $user;
        }

        return null;
    }
```